# Is it possible to use the templates from the commandline?

Tags: android

So in ADT 20 or so, there was introduced a new function to the Android Eclipse plugin, to have code templates you can use, initiated via a Wizard. I'm curious if there's any way to use those from the command line, or if I'm going to have to write my own thing to do that.

What I've gathered so far is they're FreeMarker templates, with some XML metadata to help the Wizard along.

Thanks for your time.